# SVG Absolute Pathing for `xlink:href` Attribute Not Working

Tags: svg, xlink

So I have a single SVG file that holds a collection of different paths:

```
<!-- icons.svg -->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="foo" .../>
  <path id="bar" .../>
  ...
</svg>
```

and within my webpages, I use these SVG icons:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256">
  <use xlink:href="icons.svg#foo">
</svg>
```

and this works *just fine* and exactly how I intend -- we select the SVG with the id `foo` from the `icons.svg` file.

Now, *if I try to give the `xlink:href` attribute for the `<use>` tag an _absolute_ path to my `icons.svg` file, it fails and returns nothing and seems to be unable to find the file.*.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256">
  <use xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/icons.svg#foo">
</svg>
```

It's important to note that the absolute path *is* correct.

The [documentation on `xlink` seems to suggest that absolute paths are valid values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href), which makes me wonder why it doesn't work here for me -- am I missing something?

Is there an alternative approach I should be considering? Is this currently not the approach I want to take to achieve something like this?

Comment: Is your page also from the port `8080` ? To quote chrome : "Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: @Kaiido Ah that was it -- I was on `127.0.0.1:4000`, I feel dumb :) want to make that an answer? That could help other people who run into this silly mistake as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be sure you are loading your external svg file from the same protocol and port, otherwise, browsers will block the request, according to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, **port** (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages.

<sub>(emphasize mine)</sub>